# Locate image above another with responsiveness

Tags: html, css

I would like to put one image above another, but all answers I find are using position absolute with specific pixels. I want to achieve it in a responsiveness way, so I would like to avoid strict composition.

Now my code looks like:

```html
 <style>
    .header{
      margin:20px;
      text-align:center;
    }
    .data{
      text-align:center;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <h1>Hello Stack Overflow!</h1>
    <div class="header">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/800/200/" class="background">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" class="logo">
    </div>
    <div class="data">
      <label>enter your name</label>
      <input>
    </div>
```

I would like to move the `.logo img` above the `background img` and, have different classes to move it:

- Center center;
- Center right;
- Center left;

So, my goal is having the possibility to accomplish the following image with a class that can "move" my logo, but always maintaining it above the background image. Note that the background image could have not always the same size.

[image: Goal]

I did [a plunkr to test with where you can reproduce it](http://plnkr.co/edit/XzgYco?p=preview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this answer uses absolute positioning it is responsive and should work they way you want. This answer also assumes that you have high quality background images that will not lose quality when scaled to a large size.

The logo is centered by default. There is a `.logo-right` and `.logo-left` class for side positioning.

There is a small edge case that the logo breaks out a little at small screens when the height of the background image is less than the logo. To account for this you can set the logo width to a percentage and also give it a max-width so that it doesn't enlarge too far if you are using a rasterized (non-svg) logo (see Snippet) .

```css
.header {
  margin:20px;
  text-align:center;
  position: relative;
}

.data{
  text-align:center;
}

.background {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50%;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: auto;
}

.logo-right {
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.logo-left {
  margin-left: 5%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Centered</h1>
<div class="header">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/800/200/" class="background">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" class="logo">
</div>
<div class="data">
  <label>enter your name</label>
  <input>
</div>
<h1>Right</h1>
<div class="header">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/800/200/" class="background">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" class="logo logo-right">
</div>
<div class="data">
  <label>enter your name</label>
  <input>
</div>
<h1>Left</h1>
<div class="header">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/800/200/" class="background">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" class="logo logo-left">
</div>
<div class="data">
  <label>enter your name</label>
  <input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

http://plnkr.co/edit/wd6wui?p=preview

```
<style>
.header {
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.img-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.data {
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="img-container">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/800/200/" class="background">
    </div>
    <div class="img-container">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" class="logo">
    </div>
</div>
```

Not sure I understood your question ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot @horgen, That's working, but only when I want the image "center center". I've added a wireframe image to clarify my goal.

Answer (score 0):

wrapping the images in div will do the work

```
  <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" class="logo"></div>
```